# how to put videos in one line

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put all my videos in single line instead of multiple lines.

```html
<div class="t">
   <ul>
   
  <li>somewhere I belong</li>
  <iframe  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zsCD5XCu6CM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <li>Castle of glass</li>
  <iframe  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ScNNfyq3d_w" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  
   </ul>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Place each `<iframe>` inside a `<li>`
2. Then add `display:table` to the `<div class='t'>`
3. Next, add `display:table-row` to `<ul>`
4. Last step is to add `display:table-cell` to each `<li>`

   > 5. Forgot to add `display:block` to each `iframe`

#### Snippet

```css
.t {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

ul {
  display: table-row
}

li {
  display: table-cell
}

iframe {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="t">
  <ul>

    <li>Somewhere I Belong
      <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zsCD5XCu6CM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </li>

    <li>Castle of Glass
      <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ScNNfyq3d_w" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```